# Glympse sandbox key not generated

Tags: android, glympse

I am trying to obtain a sandbox (test) key in order to test the sdk within my android application. Registering a new application at https://developer.glympse.com/apps shows empty sandbox key.

Answer (score 0):

Your API key has been created.  As an FYI, Glympse will be deprecating the SDK Lite service this month.  We also offer URL Schemes and Intents for app integration: https://developer.glympse.com/sdk/schemes_intents

We are working on a Full API service available in the near future.